# TypeScript: How can I access a variable from one scipt in another?

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I have forked a VSCode extension and would like to modify it to gain some experience.

The change I would like to make involves accessing the variable `word` at line **104** from [this script](https://github.com/fade2gray/vscode-autohotkey-plus3/blob/master/src/providers/ahkHoverProvider.ts)(#1) and making use of it in [this script](https://github.com/fade2gray/vscode-autohotkey-plus3/blob/master/src/service/helpService.ts)(#2).

I believe it may involve importing #1 into #2 and this is what I have so far...

```
import { ConfigKey, Global } from '../common/global';
import { Process } from '../common/processWrapper';
import { AhkHoverProvider } from '../providers/ahkHoverProvider';

export class HelpService {
    public static open(): void {
        var command = word; // access 'word' from AhkHoverProvider
        const helpPath = Global.getConfig(ConfigKey.helpPath);
        const commandPath = command ? '::/docs/commands/' + command + '.htm' : '';
        // Process.exec(`C:/Windows/hh.exe ${helpPath}`);
        Process.exec(`C:/Windows/hh.exe ms-its:` + helpPath + commandPath);
    }
}
```

I have tried reading up on examples of TypeScript classes and export/import, but I'm at a loss on how to progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "word" only in the HoverProvider because it depends by the position of your cursor (document and position).
You can find additional info on [vscode api docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features)

Your entry point is `AhkHoverProvider.provideHover` [L38](https://github.com/fade2gray/vscode-autohotkey-plus3/blob/master/src/providers/ahkHoverProvider.ts#L38) and you can start from here passing word to your Service.

```js
interface Context {
    /** The character after the word */
    charAfter: string;
    word: string;
}

export class AhkHoverProvider implements HoverProvider {

    public async provideHover(
        document: TextDocument,
        position: Position,
        token: CancellationToken,
    ) {
        const context = this.buildContext(document, position);
        // context.word is accessible here
        HelpService.openOnCommand(context.word);
    }
}
```

HelpService.ts

```js
import { ConfigKey, Global } from '../common/global';
import { Process } from '../common/processWrapper';

export class HelpService {
    public static open(): void {
        const helpPath = Global.getConfig(ConfigKey.helpPath);
        Process.exec(`C:/Windows/hh.exe ${helpPath}`);
    }

    public static openOnCommand(command: string): void {
        const helpPath = Global.getConfig(ConfigKey.helpPath);
        const commandPath = `::/docs/commands/${command}.htm`;
        Process.exec(`C:/Windows/hh.exe ms-its:${helpPath}${commandPath}`);
    }
}
```